# Creating a group specifically for password manager, how does that work?

Tags: password, group

When you use a password manager (client side) on linux, I read that you should place the password database in a directory with OWNER and GROUP "passman" or something.

Then do the same to the password database files... That's fine, I can do that.

So then only the password manager can read or write the file or even see in that directory (besides root).

But how is that password manager supposed to be able to access it?
Like how do I tie the manager into the group??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would run the password manager program with the same user & group (or their IDs) so that the program can manage the associated files and directories.

This is a very common practice for programs that run as services. A number of such programs automatically set up a user & group during the installation process, and then include the configuration to run as the same user & group. Examples include the Apache web server, Docker, and the Postgres database.

The actual switching process varies from one software to the next. Some have configuration parameters to accept the user/group names, and then change to it programmatically. Others use systemd's capabilities to run as a specific user and group. I am sure that there are even more options available.